# Não consigo exibir dados populados em divs separados por colunas

Tags: php, html, pdo

Quero exibir dados de uma tabela por divs com colunas de tamanho especifico para cada uma delas, porém, quando carrego as informações, traz todos eles numa mesma coluna, não quero usar com tags table para formata-las. Vejam como está aparecendo aqui.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
                            echo "<div class='col-md-2'>";

                            echo "<div class='widget widget-default widget-item-icon'>";
                                echo "<div class='widget-item-left'>";
                                    echo "<span class='fa fa-building-o'></span>";
                                echo "</div>";                             
                                echo "<div class='widget-data'>";

                                        while ($row_aprt = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                                                    extract($row_aprt);                                                        

                                                    echo "<div class='widget-int num-count'>{$num_apart}</div>";
                                                    echo "<div class='widget-title'>{$nm_apart} - {$tipo_apart}</div>";
                                                    echo "<div class='widget-subtitle'>Disponivel - {$disponivel}</div>";

                                            } 

                                echo "</div>";                                    
                            echo "</div>";
                        echo "</div>";
```

Comment: Defina uma div com a class row do Bootstrap pra comportar as outras, dentro dessa div crie as outras com a class col-md-2 trazendo suas informações

Comment: Na verdade já tinha colocado um div com uma class row, mesmo com ele ainda está apresentando esta pequena falha de formatação

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade havia o seguinte problema: ao colocar todo o conteúdo do laço while dentro de uma `<div class='col-md-2'>`, o conteudo não cabia em uma unica "linha" e quebrava para a proxima, ficando apenas uma coluna de conteudo (que é o esperado ao se fazer isso). Então, para resolver o problema basta coloca apenas o conteudo de dentro do laço while dentro de `<div class='col-md-2'>` e adicionar a classe `row` na div `<div class='widget-data'>`. Alterando o codigo fica:

```
<?php
echo "<div class='widget widget-default widget-item-icon'>";
echo "<div class='widget-item-left'>";
echo "<span class='fa fa-building-o'></span>";
echo "</div>";                   
/***********************************************************
Definindo uma linha para conter os dados do laço while (class row do bootstrap)
***********************************************************/          
echo "<div class='widget-data row'>";

while ($row_aprt = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    extract($row_aprt);      
    /*****************************************************************
    Conteudo para cada duas colunas
    *****************************************************************/                                                  
    echo "<div class='col-md-2'>";
    echo "<div class='widget-int num-count'>{$num_apart}</div>";
    echo "<div class='widget-title'>{$nm_apart} - {$tipo_apart}</div>";
    echo "<div class='widget-subtitle'>Disponivel - {$disponivel}</div>";
    echo "</div>"; 
}                                    
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
?>
```